# How to have a type in Closure Compiler externs without a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am trying to make externs for the Google Closure Compiler for types that have no constructor.

I have tried the following, but it gives me a `Bad type annotation. Unknown type WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom` error because nothing tells the compiler that `WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom` is a type instead of just a collection of methods/properties.

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Declares externs for the Windows media player ActiveX control.
 * @author Joshua Dwire
 * @suppress {duplicate}
 */

var WindowsMediaActiveX={};


/**
 * Methods and properties for accessing a CD or DVD in its drive.
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom={};


/**
 * Retrieves the CD or DVD drive letter.
 * @type {string}
 * @readonly
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom.prototype.driveSpecifier;



/**
 * Methods and properties for accessing a collection of CD or DVD drives.
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.CdromCollection={};


/**
 * Retrieves the Cdrom object associated with a particular drive letter.
 * @param {string} driveSpecifier String containing the drive letter followed by a colon (":") character.
 * @returns {WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom}
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.CdromCollection.prototype.getByDriveSpecifier=function(driveSpecifier){};
```

I know I could change:

```
/**
 * Methods and properties for accessing a CD or DVD in its drive.
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom={};
```

to:

```
/**
 * Methods and properties for accessing a CD or DVD in its drive.
 * @constructor
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom=function(){};
```

but then the compiler wouldn't show a warning if I or someone else tried to use `new WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom()`. Any ideas on how to define this?

For those of you who want more information, I am working on a media player that will use the Windows Media ActiveX Control to play media. I am also using the Google Closure Compiler and Library. I need to define the externs for the player to work correctly, but none of the types used by the ActiveX Control have constructors. They are all created through other methods or through creating an object in the html. How should I define this in the extern file? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why is the .prototype property being set on an arbitrary object? Objects doesn't have a default prototype (`({}).prototype` is undefined), and they can't be constructed to make use of the prototype anyway. Are these ActiveX components making use of some prototypes in a way I'm not familiar with?

Comment: All of the objects are created by something other than the new keyword. The ActiveX component creates all of the objects, and I need to define the externs for them. Externs are specific to the Closure Compiler. Are you familiar with the Closure Compiler?

Comment: So ActiveX probably does something like `var f = function () {}; f.prototype = WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom.prototype; new f()` under the hood? I wouldn't be surprised if the Closure Compiler does not support this with it's special knowledge of the `prototype` property. My usage of the Compiler has been very basic though, and only with advanced mode compatible JS (no fancy hacky stuff). My next step would be to ask on the closure-compiler mailing list hosted on Google Groups, a lot of Googlers are active there.

Comment: The `WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom` is just something I am defining so I have a type to refer to. In reality, the objects will be created by inserting HTML code (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564350(v=vs.85).aspx) or by calling a method on the player element. These methods will be added by ActiveX. For more Windows Media Player SDK docs, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564034(v=vs.85).aspx. I did go ahead and post on Google Groups, but I'll have to wait for my post to be approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical annotation for this pattern is:

```
/** @const */
var WindowsMediaActiveX = {};

/**
 * Methods and properties for accessing a CD or DVD in its drive.
 * @constructor
 * @private
 */
WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom=function(){};
```

The `@private` annotation is the indication that the constructor is not meant to be directly called. However, the compiler will only report a warning on direct instantiations of the type when the accessControls warning group is enabled (on with VERBOSE warnings).

Edit: Answer updated to add the required `@const` annotation to the namespace. The access control annotations will be ignored otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this doesn't seem to work. I added the `@private` tag so the declaration now looks exactly like in your answer. I also am now passing the `--jscomp_error=accessControls`, `--jscomp_error=visibility`, and `--warning_level=VERBOSE` flags to the compiler, but when I call `var test=new WindowsMediaActiveX.Cdrom()`, I still don't get an error. On the other hand, If I remove the `@constructor` tag from the declaration, I then get the errors I was having before. Is the `@private` tag being ignored because the declaration is in an extern file?

Comment: Possibly. This seems like a bug though. Let me do some testing.

Comment: If it helps, Here is my compiler version info: 
`Version: 20120917 (revision 2180)` 
`Built on: 2012/09/17 14:33`

Comment: If you think this is a bug, I can file a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/list.

Comment: I think this should be considered a bug. Can you post it to the issue tracker please? We'll see how the rest of the team feels about it.

Comment: Just filed the report at https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=852

Comment: Any idea what the the team's response to the report was?

Comment: Yes - `@const` is required on the namespace. Then it should work. The answer has been updated.

Comment: That works perfectly. Any idea why the `@const` attribute is required? Is that still a bug, or can I somehow close the report?

Comment: It's a bug. Leave the report open. It's low priority but at least we can keep track of it.